# Spinner.setSelection doesn't trigger OnItemSelectedListener properly

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm currently working on a Account Management Activity for my Android application and I'm having trouble figuring out why the [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29) method from a spinner does not trigger the OnItemSelectedListener attached to said Spinner.

Here is what I have currently;

onCreate() method :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.account_management);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    retreiveLanguage();
    initializeUI();

    // Vérification si l'usager est déjà connecté
    Globals appState = ((Globals) this.getApplication());
    boolean userLoggedIn = appState.isUserLoggedIn();
    boolean userInfoAvailable = appState.isUserInfoAvailable();

    if (userLoggedIn && userInfoAvailable) {
      fillUI();
    }
}
```

Pertinent lines from the initializeUI() method which is called on the Activity's creation which shows the binding of the Spinner the Listener :

```
    /** OnItemSelectedHandler for the Country Spinner */
    mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCountrySelected() was called, position : " + pos);

            mProvinces = new ArrayList<String>();
            mProvincesCode = new ArrayList<String>();

            mXML.parseResponse(FileManager.getInstance().getPortalOptions());

            for (int i = 0; i < mXML.getCountry(pos).sizeProvinces(); i++){
                mProvinces.add(mXML.getCountry(pos).getProvince(i).getLabel(mLanguage));
                mProvincesCode.add(mXML.getCountry(pos).getProvince(i).getCode());
            }

            mProvinceArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ManageAccountActivity.this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mProvinces);
            mProvinceArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mProvinceSpinner.setAdapter(mProvinceArrayAdapter);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Do Nothing ...               
        }
    });
```

And again another couple lines, this time from the fillUI method() :

```
Log.i(TAG, "Setting country based on user information.");
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_country))
    .setSelection(mCountriesCode.indexOf(mUser.getCountry()));
// TODO : Fix Provinces and States not being changed accordingly
Log.i(TAG, "Setting province based on user information.");
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_province))
    .setSelection(mProvincesCode.indexOf(mUser.getProvince()));
```

So with this I would expect the OnItemSelectedListener to be called right after I set the selection in the fillUI() method, but that's not what's happening at runtime :S

Here's my LogCat extract that shows that the Listener isn't called when the selection is applied to the country spinner:

> I/ManageAccountActivity(28108): Setting country based on user information.
>
> I/ManageAccountActivity(28108): Setting province based on user information.
>
> I/ManageAccountActivity(28108): onCountrySelected() was called, position : 1

As an experiment, I also tried putting the fillUI() call in the onStart method of my Activity but that didn't change how the application reacted.

Thanks in advance for any pointers, help or tips !

Comment: ,OnItemSelectedListener is fired only when you do some action on spinner..to change

Comment: Well I do change it ... moving the selection from 0 to 1 wouldn't that be considered changed ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried to set the spinner by using two arguments, the second using a boolean:

```
.setSelection(mProvincesCode.indexOf(mUser.getProvince()), true);
```

From the [developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) it shows:

```
setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
//Jump directly to a specific item in the adapter data.
```

Comment: I've tried it with the animate argument being false (got it from another thread) I'll try it with the argument being set to true.

Comment: Well thank you very much, I should've tried setting it to true in the first place :P. Setting both spinners' to setSelection(pos, true) did the trick.

Comment: I've just tested this and using the method with `animate` indeed triggers `onItemSelected` while the one without does not.

Comment: Why is Android so broken!

Comment: does not work for me either :( 
@AmanGoel answer also does not work for me

Comment: I've lost 2hours looking for this answer. How it can be so hard do this simple thing?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following code:

```
  ownerSpinnerVw.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             ownerSpinnerVw.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem being adding this to the onCreate method.  The program works but only for the first selection.  The second time I select the program crashes the emulator.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned in your post. This answer is not working. Please add it as a comment.